# org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a service where user can download archive

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{resource}/zip", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/zip")
    public void downloadArchive(@PathVariable("resource") String resource, HttpServletResponse response) {
        SomeResource some= someResourceService.get(resource); //If no resource found custom NoDataException.class is thrown
        //archive and write out to response object 
}
```

which should produce zip.

I also have and exception handler method

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoDataException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ExceptionMessage> handleNoResultException(Exception e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ExceptionMessage(e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

which produces application/json

I expect to receive 404 if no resource is found. But I get 500 with

> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: Can you post the complete stack?

Comment: What does the "Accept" header look like on incoming requests?  Is it just "application/zip"?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466207/could-not-find-acceptable-representation-using-spring-boot-starter-web