# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation spring mvc 4.1.5 with com.fasterxml 2.5.1

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Help - what else can I do to fix this error?    org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException:: Could not find acceptable representation.

I think my project is configured properly to handle json restful requests. In the past several days, I have read and applied various suggestions to no avail. Are there any more ideas on what else I should be doing differently?

I am using Spring MVC 4.1.5 and com.fasterxml 2.5.1.

A portion of my pom.xml

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
 </dependency>
```

Here is my part of my web.xml

```xml
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is part of my servlet-context.xml

```xml
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.losgatos">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Here is my controller

```
package com.losgatos.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.losgatos.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping( "user" )
public class UserController { 

    @RequestMapping( value = "data", produces="application/json" )
    public User getUser(){
        return new User();
    }   
}
```

Here is the User User POJO

```
package com.losgatos;

import java.util.EnumSet;

public class User {

    public User(){
        id = 0;
        age = 22;
        name = "Titus Feng"; 
        alias = "tornado tie";
        roles = EnumSet.of( Role.NORMAL, Role.NEW );
    }

    private int id, age;
    private String name, alias;
    private EnumSet<Role> roles;

    //added getters and setters here

    public enum Role{
        NEW, NORMAL, ADMIN, MEMBER, DORMANT 
    }   
}
```

Comment: can you show us AJAX configuration how you calling REST service?

Comment: At the moment, I am calling http://localhost:8080/user/data directly from the browser just to test that it works as planned

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466207/could-not-find-acceptable-representation-using-spring-boot-starter-web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gotten it to work finally by:
removing `<type>bundle</type>` from my fasterxml.jackson pom.xml entries
rerunning my pom.xml file
cleaning the project build (project -> clean)
 
cleaning and restarting the server

Answer (score 2):

In your spring context configuration file(dispatcher-servlet.xml) you have:

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.losgatos">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" />
</context:component-scan>
```

and your controller is annotated with:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( "user" )
public class UserController { 
...
}
```

your controller class will not be loaded to container at all. BTW as per your exception message:

> I am getting the error
>
> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException:: Could
>   not find acceptable representation.

This exception raises when you have not registered the following in context file:

- `<mvc:annotation-driven />`  (you have not registered on your context file)
- If required JAR's are not present on classpath, (you already have it)
- When ENUM is used, annotate your ENUM class with `@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)`

EDIT:
tested working fine for me, with Spring 4.0.1.RELEASE and below single JSON dependency:

com.fasterxml.jackson.core
    jackson-databind
    2.4.3

and controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/u")
public class UserRestController {

    @RequestMapping( value = "/data", produces="application/json" )
    public RestUser getUser(){
        return new RestUser();
    } 
}
```

got:

```
{"id":0,"age":22,"name":"Titus Feng","alias":"tornado tie","roles":["NEW","NORMAL"]}
```

Suggestion,
change this:

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.losgatos">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" />
</context:component-scan>
```

to:

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="com.losgatos">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Rembo. My spring context file already uses <annotation-driven />. Spring version prefers it to <mvc:annotation-driven />. I have annotated the ENUM class with @JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT) but I continue to get the same error message.

Comment: your suggested component-scan replacement rule is missing. Could you add it?

Comment: hey @Rembo, could you add the missing replacement component-scan rule?

Comment: I applied your new component scan, @Rembo,  and continued to get the same error message

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Framework 4.1 raised some dependencies requirements](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-Spring-Framework#libraries); you need to upgrade Jackson to version 2.3 or later. Note that the artifact groupId changed to `com.fasterxml`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @Brian.
I have replaced the org.codehaus with core.fasterxml libraries.

I continued to get the same error:
class org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException occured:: Could not find acceptable representation

I also noticed errors in fasterxml dependency tags of my pom.xml file that say 
Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:bundle:2.5.1
It did not prevent maven from installing the core.fasterxml dependencies though which is good.