# upgrading spring boot with groovy controller returns 406 causing HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, groovy

I have a Groovy application that I am dealing with which is having some odd behavior when upgrading from spring-boot 1.3.0.RELEASE to 1.4.0.RELEASE. The controller always returns a 406 on any error and I am not sure what type of content it expects to return. The code is below:

SomeController.groovy:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping('/some/mapping')
class SomeController extends AbstractController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService

    @RequestMapping(path = '/abc/{some_param}/some_action', method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    @PreAuthorize('isAuthenticated() && (principal.username == #username || principal.admin)')
    void setValue(@PathVariable String some_param, @RequestBody String body_content) throws ValidationException, NotFoundException {

        handleViolations(validate(AnObject, [some_param: some_param, body: body_content]))

        try {
            someService.setValue(some_param, body_content)
        } catch(AlreadyExistsException e) {
            throw new ValidationException([body: 'IN_USE'])
        }
    }
}
```

SomeControllerSpec.groovy < The test...

```
class AccountControllerSpec extends AbstractControllerSpec {
    static final BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/'
    def client = new CustomRESTClient(BASE_URL)

    // This test fails 
    def 'testing api'() {
        //Expected 400 bad request but receiving a 406 not acceptable
        client.put(
            path: "/api/abc/fake_param/some_action",
            // The body doesn't conform to the expectations of the API
            body: 'blah',
            contentType: MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE
        ).status == HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST

        // Exception thrown:
        // INFO 22125 --- [tp1838490665-22] c.c.w.c.RestEndpointsConfiguration       : org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    }
}
```

The Exception in the logs:

```
INFO 22125 --- [tp1838490665-22] c.c.w.c.RestEndpointsConfiguration       : org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

I have tried many things including setting the expected header type:

```
client.setHeaders(accept: MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
```

I have been trying various other things but to no avail. The exception persists.

**Note:** The action at the endpoint completes as expected.

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29022759/5813861), may be it may help you

Comment: We're using gradle but I searched. That link did not help with our issue. Thanks for the suggestion!