# Spring Rest Controller String response

Tags: java, spring, rest, get

I have a Spring Controller for Rest service:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
public class SampleController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getText", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testMethod(@RequestParam("locale") final  String locale) {
        return  "Hello Worlds TEXT";
    }
}
```

When I perform a GET request at `https://localhost:9002/sample/getText?locale=en`, I will get error *"Could not find acceptable representation"*. But I need a plain text. Could you please explain how I can get a simple text?

The ["Could not find acceptable representation" using spring-boot-starter-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466207/could-not-find-acceptable-representation-using-spring-boot-starter-web) not resolved my problem

I have stackTrace:

```
06 Mar 2018 14:44:20,097 ERROR [hybrisHTTP19] [RestHandlerExceptionResolver] org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:251)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:154)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:254)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:343)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224)
        at com.wiley.ws.core.filter.TransactionFilter.doFilter(TransactionFilter.java:55)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224)
        at com.wiley.ws.core.v3.filter.DisableRestrictionsFilter.doFilter(DisableRestrictionsFilter.java:47)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224)
        at com.wiley.ws.core.auth.GuestRoleFilter.doFilterInternal(GuestRoleFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224)
        at com.wiley.ws.core.v2.filter.UserMatchingFilter.doFilterInternal(UserMatchingFilter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:152)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224)
        at com.wiley.ws.core.filter.SessionAttributesFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionAttributesFilter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224)
        at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.RestSessionFilter.doFilter(RestSessionFilter.java:49)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:45)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224)
        at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:45)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:224)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:154)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.filter.SessionHidingFilter.doFilter(SessionHidingFilter.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:168)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:293)
        at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:247)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.Log4JAccessLogValve.invoke(Log4JAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Try the `MediaType` instead of a String-literal: `produces = org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could not find acceptable representation" using spring-boot-starter-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466207/could-not-find-acceptable-representation-using-spring-boot-starter-web)

Comment: Remove `@ResponseBody` from your method

Comment: Mr. Polywhirl, if I place **produces = org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN**, the compile time error occur.

Comment: Replace `produces = "text/plain"`  by `produces =
 { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }`

Comment: How do you perform the GET? Please add the request headers. You are probably setting 'Accept: application/json' or something like that.

Comment: Cyril, I have performed it at Google Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.
Spring's AbstractHttpMessageConverter functionality are customized for my project. I didn't know about it when I asked this question.
There were no any converters for text/plain. There was only one Jaxb2HttpMessageConverter converter for json.
I have added the converter:

```
 <bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
            <list>
                <util:constant id="text_plain" static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And now the code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
public class SampleController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getText", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testMethod(@RequestParam("locale") final  String locale) {
        return  "Hello Worlds TEXT";
    }
}
```

works fine.
Hope this will help somebody

Answer (score 2):

Hey Your code just working fine. I have tried the same. please see the code below. Please make sure you are send get request is correct.

```
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sample")
    public class SampleController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/getText", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")
        @ResponseBody
        public String testMethod(@RequestParam("locale") final String locale) {
            return "Hello Worlds TEXT";
        }
    }
```

Please see the request response screenshot from browser.

[image]

Comment: Paras Sharma, When I perform request at Chrome, the exception will throw

06 Mar 2018 14:44:20,097 ERROR [hybrisHTTP19] [RestHandlerExceptionResolver] org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:251)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters

Comment: @Dron4K Are you using spring mvc ? if yes can you please share spring-servlet.xml

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of @ResponseBody annotation:

> The @ResponseBody annotation tells a controller that the object returned is automatically serialized into JSON and passed back into the HttpResponse object.
>   [see more](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body)

Answer (score 1):

It okay with me, just make client with right controller and service. You should have "application/plain" for ClientResponse, like:

```
        Client client = Client.create();    
        WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8181/SpringMVC/sample/getText.do?locale=en");    
        ClientResponse response = resource.accept("application/plain").get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Your Rest client controller would be:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    RESTfulClient rESTfulClient;

    @RequestMapping(value = "showResponse")
    public String getResponse() {
        String respose = rESTfulClient.getResponse();
        System.out.println("output: "+respose);
        return "showCustomer";
    }
}
```

And Rest client service would be like:

```
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
    import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

    @Service
    public class RESTfulClient {

       public String getResponse(){
           String output="hello";
             try {
                    Client client = Client.create();    
                    WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:9002/SpringMVC/sample/getText.do?locale=en");    
                    ClientResponse response = resource.accept("application/plain").get(ClientResponse.class);

                    if(response.getStatus() == 200){

                        output = response.getEntity(String.class);
                        System.out.println(output);    

                    }else System.out.println("Somthing went wrong..!");        

                  } catch (Exception e) {    
                          e.printStackTrace();    
                  }
            return output;

            }   
    }
```

Comment: @Paras Sharma , did you get it?